# How to override http.py methods in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I want to override `setup_db` method for my add-on because in current situation you can't take argument from `url` with db name, and if the user has more than 1 database I can`t run my login link from incognito.

I don't want the user to go to `/web/database/selector` first.

I was thinking about the user going to `/web/login?db=example_db_name` and then somehow redirect to my login link.

("somehow" because if you type it, it redirects you to /web/login, so i cant add redirect from login page).

I'm doing that assuming that in `odoo.conf` user has

```
db_name = False, dbfilter = .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you faced the same problem, here is my solution. It`s overriding the default method which is kinda bad usually, but in our situation there isnt much we can do.

```
from odoo import http

class Rooting(http.Root):
    def setup_db(self, httprequest):
        db = httprequest.session.db
        # Check if session.db is legit
        if db:
            if db not in http.db_filter([db], httprequest=httprequest):
                httprequest.session.logout()
                db = None
        if not db:
            if 'db' in httprequest.args:
                db = httprequest.args['db']
                httprequest.session.db = db
        if not db:
            httprequest.session.db = http.db_monodb(httprequest)


http.Root.setup_db = Rooting.setup_db
```